# Any ideas why the server I am launching would be crashing when a request is made to it?

Tags: c#, .net-core, timer, filesystemwatcher

The server works perfectly when I run it directly. When I launch the server using the following code, it is closing and then restarting.. any ideas what I might be missing? My initial thought was the server was triggering the OnChange event when a request was being made to it. But no changes are logged.. I'm stumped.

```
   internal static class Program
{
    private static Timer _timer = new Timer
    { Interval = 1000, Enabled = true, AutoReset = true };

    private static DateTime _lastChange;

    private static void Main()
    {

        using var watcher =
            new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootWatchDirectory"])
            {
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                               | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                               | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                               | NotifyFilters.FileName
                               | NotifyFilters.Security
                               | NotifyFilters.Size
            };


        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;

        _timer.Elapsed += OnInterval;

        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnInterval(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        var processes =
            Process.GetProcessesByName(server);

        var changeDetectWaitTimeInSeconds = int.Parse(10);

        if (processes.Length != 0) return;

        var ticksElapsed = now.Ticks - _lastChange.Ticks;

        var ticksToWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(changeDetectWaitTimeInSeconds).Ticks;

        if (ticksElapsed > ticksToWait)
            PowerShell
                .Create()
                .AddCommand("Start-Process")
                .AddParameter("FilePath", 
                    "server.exe")
                .Invoke();
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Changed) return;

        _lastChange = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine($"Changed: {e.FullPath}");

        PowerShell
            .Create()
            .AddCommand("Stop-Process")
            .AddParameter("Name", "server")
            .Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose? To run an exe unless a certain file is placed somewhere, the exe sees it and shuts down? Would it be simpler to make it a service and tell the windows SCM to stop it?

Comment: Essentially we are running a node server alongside an IIS Website. When we publish the IIS Site we need this node server to be stopped, and then restarted after the website has finished publishing. I actually just resolved the issue.. I needed to run the set-location command to set the working directory on the powershell command.

Comment: You can post it up into an answer; you never know who else will need the advice in the future! :D